# Using assert raises unit testing in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception

Currently I'm writing a unittest for my class function.

```
def test_getitem(self):
    test1 = List(3)
    for i in range(3):
        test1.append(i)
    self.assertEqual(test1[2], 2)

    test1 = List(3)
    for i in range(3):
        test1.append(i)
    self.assertRaises(IndexError, test1[4])
```

the problem I'm having now is at the `self.assertRaises` part of my code. I'm not sure if that is how it's done but when I run the `unittest`, it produces an error `Index out of range`. By right, it should be "OK".

`List` is my class and `List(3)` creates an array based list. so when i `test1.append(i)`, it is now `[0,1,2]`.

`test1[2]` is a method of calling the `getitem` function in my class similar to `self[index]`.

I'm wondering if I'm assert raising correctly? `self.assertEqual` is fine.

Comment: When you call `assertRaises()` like this you need to pass a callable as the second argument. So `self.assertRaises(IndexError, lambda: test1[4])` would work, but @AK47's answer is the recommended way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `with` statement when you're asserting for exceptions being thrown

```
def test_getitem(self):
    test1 = List(3)
    for i in range(3):
        test1.append(i)
    self.assertEqual(test1[2], 2)

    test1 = List(3)
    for i in range(3):
        test1.append(i)
    with self.assertRaises(IndexError):
        test1[4]
```

Answer (score 6):

Arguments are evaluated before the function is called, so when you use `test1[4]` it's executed before the [`self.assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) is called. So it's not able to catch the exception.

That's also the reason why the 2-argument form has the signature `assertRaises(exception, msg=None)`, the second argument here is the "msg" to match, not the function that is to be called. So it wouldn't have done the correct thing in any case.

You could use the context manager:

```
with self.assertRaises(IndexError):
    test1[4]
```

Or use the multiple argument form:

```
self.assertRaises(IndexError, test1.__getitem__, 4)
```